# How to plot solid in matlab or R?

Tags: r, matlab, plot

I have a `3D` region enclosed by following 3 equations and the axes.
`x+y<1` , `x>(z/(1+z))*(1-y)` , `x>1-((1+z)*y/z)`.
`x` , `y` and `z` are bounded at `0` and `1`.

Following matlab code generates the 3D plot, I want to show the bounded region as a solid. How to do that ?

```
y=0:0.05:1; %v2
z=0:0.05:1; % delta
[Y,Z]= meshgrid(y,z);
X = 1-Y;
axis([0 1 0 1 0 1]);
surf(X,Y,Z);
hold on;
X = (Z./(1+Z))*(1-Y);
axis([0 1 0 1 0 1]);
surf(X,Y,Z);
X = 1-((1+Z)./Z)*Y;
axis([0 1 0 1 0 1]);
surf(X,Y,Z);
```

Kindly limit the solution to `Matlab` or `R`.

Answer (score 2):

% build a tessellation of a unit cube as a simplicial complex
sc = tessellatelattice({0:.1:1,0:.1:1,0:.1:1});

% Truncate it to create a right triangular prism,
% such that x + y <= 1
sc = planartruncate(sc,[.5 .5 0],-[1 1 0]);

% extract the points, to create a set of nonlinear constraints
x = sc.domain(:,1);
y = sc.domain(:,2);
z = sc.domain(:,3);
% Build the nonlinear surface constraints
sc.range = [x - (z./(1+z)).*(1-y), x - (1-((1+z).*y./z))];

% truncate away the part that fails those constraints
%  x>(z/(1+z))*(1-y)
sc = isotruncate(sc,0,1,'range','above');

%  x>1-((1+z)*y/z)
sc = isotruncate(sc,0,2,'range','above');

% plot the resulting blob
plotsc(sc,'marker','none')

[image: triangulated blob]

As you can see, it is a right triangular prism, but with two "faces" that are sort of hyperbolic.

[image: blob]

This uses my simplicialcomplex toolbox, something I occasionally give out, but have not posted, as it takes a bit of effort to learn to use. Once learnt, it is a useful thing, IF one is willing to spend the effort to learn it.